# Fourier transform of the Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Can someone refer me on the Fourier transform of the fourier transform or clarify it for me?

It is known that the F.T. of the F.T. is some small modification of the original function itself, but I can't find anything about this online.

Comment: If i recall correctly, Fourier transform of a Fourier transform of $f(x)$ gives us the function $f(-x)$

Comment: @Adam That's exactly what i'm looking for. Where can I find a more detailed source with explanation? ALso, this doesn't make sense to me intuitively

Comment: I'll check my notes. It's like i said. It's a direct conclusion from the formula for Fourier inverse transform

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem

Comment: You can prove it using $2\pi\delta(x)=\int_\mathbb{R}\exp ikx dk$.

Comment: Also notice that it is not always possible to take the Fourier transform twice. For instance, if $f\in L^1$, then $\hat{f}\notin L^1$ in general.

Comment: @Jakobian When you are working on a locally compact abelian group which is isomorphic to its dual group

Comment: Related question https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29866/fourier-transform-of-a-fourier-transform

Answer (score 11):

The Fourier transform of $f$ is:
$$F(\omega)=\mathscr{F}(f(t))\{\omega\}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t f(t) e^{-i \omega t}$$
Transforming it again:
$$g(\tau)=\mathscr{F}(F(\omega))\{\tau\}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d} \omega e^{-i \tau \omega}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t f(t) e^{-i \omega t}$$
Changing the order of integrations:
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t f(t) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d} \omega e^{-i \omega t} e^{-i \omega \tau}$$
And $\mathscr{F}(e^{i a t})\{\omega\}=2 \pi \delta(\omega -a)$:
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t f(t) 2 \pi \delta(t + \tau)$$
$$=2 \pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}t f(t) \delta(t + \tau)$$
$$=2 \pi f(-\tau)$$
But you might get a different result with a different definition of the FT.

Answer (score 3):

We have that $$ f(x) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathfrak{F}(f)(s)e^{2\pi\cdot isx} ds $$
And from this
$$ f(x) = \mathfrak{ F}\circ\mathfrak{ F}(f)(-x) $$
Because all we do, is take the Fourier transform of $\mathfrak{F}(f)(s)$ with respect to $-x$

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to see in the finite case. The
[Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform)
is given by multiplication by the $\, n \!\times\! n\,$ DFT (Vandermonde) matrix. Define
$\, e_n(x) := \exp(2\pi\sqrt{-1}x/n),\,$ and matrix $\, T(n) := \{\frac1{\sqrt{n}}e_n(i j)\}_{i,j}.\,$ The
matrix $\,A(n) := T(n)^2\,$ is 
 $\, A(n)_{i,j} = \frac1n\!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e_n((i\!+\!j)k)\,$
but $\, d_n(j) := \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e_n(jk) \,$ evaluates to $\, d_n(j) = n\,$ if
$\, j \equiv 0 \pmod n\,$ and $\, d_n(j) = 0\,$ otherwise. This implies that
$\, A(n)_{i,j} = 1\,$ if  $\, i \equiv -j \pmod n\,$ and  $\,A(n)_{j,j} = 0\,$ otherwise.

Thus, $\,A(n)\,$ takes any vector $\,(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})\,$ to
$\,(x_0,x_{n-1},\dots,x_1).\,$ 
 This corresponds to $\,\mathscr{F}^2\!: f(x) \mapsto f(-x)\,$ in the continuous Fourier transform case.