# Show that $F^4=I$ if $F$ is the Fourier Transform.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform

Let the Fourier Transfor $F:L_2(\mathbb{R})\to L_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $\displaystyle Fg(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)e^{ixt}dt\,\,$ for $\,\,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I need to show that  $F^4=I$. Can you give me some suggestions to try this please

I know that $\displaystyle F^{-1}h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)e^{-ixt}dt\,\,$ but
but I'm not sure if that could be used to prove that $F^4=I$.

Answer (score 3):

Given $g\in L_2(\mathbb R)$, you can prove that $(F \circ F)g(x)=g(-x)$ (as can be seen in this question: [Fourier transform of the Fourier transform?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803496/fourier-transform-of-the-fourier-transform). Here, they define Fourier Transform without $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, but I'm sure you can deal with that).

Then, you just need to see that $F^4=F^2\circ F^2$.