# Is the $2\pi$ factor present in the Fourier transform of a Fourier transform?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I have an issue. I want to prove what the Fourier transform of a Fourier Transform is. Let $f(t)$ be the analysed function and $F(\omega)$ its fourier transform. One book claims that $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}(f(t))) = f(-t)$. I believe that $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}(f(t)))=2\pi f(-t)$ is more likely. Starting from there:

$$\mathcal{F}(f(t))=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-i\omega t}d\omega$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}(f(t)))=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(T)e^{-i\omega T}dT\right]e^{-i\omega t}d\omega$$

Using that $\mathcal{F}(e^{i\omega_0t})=2\pi \delta(\omega-\omega_0)$ I get the $2\pi$ result.

Please help !

---

NB: I consider the non-symmetric Fourier transform, so you have a $1/2\pi$ for the inverse transform.

---

**UPDATE**: some comments say that it depends on the Fourier transform definition. I don't understand that. This a duality property. I.e., the inverse fourier transform of a fourier transform will *always* equal $f(t)$, regardless of the definition of the Fourier transform, right ?

Comment: Does this question help? [Fourier transform of the Fourier transform?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803496/fourier-transform-of-the-fourier-transform)

Comment: Don't use ChatGPT for math things.

Comment: ChatGPT is not a computer algebra system.  It doesn't understand mathematics, and absolutely should not be seen as a source of knowledge regarding mathematics. You need to read an actual text (either physical book or quality online text) on the topic.

Comment: ChatGPT is glorified text prediction, and little more. It doesn't actually think or "know" anything. (Examples: [1](https://c.vxtwitter.com/tasty_gigabyte7/status/1620571251344551938), [2](https://i.imgur.com/EaHd0pi.png))

Comment: I mean, the first mistake is trusting ChatGPT at all, but anyway, the definition of Fourier transforms is not the same between authors (different normalisations are suited for different things) so there will be constants here and there which are gonna be different. This does mean that it's almost always better to manually check which constants you get for which normalisation, or to have some table ready I guess.

Comment: Regarding your question, different texts may have slightly different definitions, largely depending on a choice of how the transform is normalized.  Some texts will include a factor of $2\pi$, while others will not.  It really comes down to the precise definition of the transform you are working with.

Comment: There are several different, effectively equivalent, definitions for the Fourier transform. If your transform is symmetric and of the form $e^{2\pi ixy}$, no factor of $2\pi$ is necessary. If it is symmetric and of the form $e^{ixy}$, you can split the $2\pi$ as a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ on both. Or if you don't want it to be symmetric, you can slap a $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ on either the forward or inverse transform. Some don't even bother and instead allow the Fourier transform to not be unitary on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (which I find abhorrent).

Comment: Moral of the story: don't trust ChatGPT. AI are not knowledge engines: they (for now) effectively regurgitate and riff on information they have been trained on. When you have something as subtle as this question, AI are going to get it very wrong because there are very minor differences and they are not going to be able to discern the truth of the matter.

Comment: Regarding the precedent comments, I removed the mention of ChatGPT. I think you misunderstood my approach: in no circumstances would I find a demonstration with ChatGPT. I graduated in engineering and did the demonstration by myself. I only asked him when I had no more idea.

Comment: We did not insinuate (or at least I did not) that you used ChatGPT for the demonstration. Not like it would matter, since a correct proof is a correct proof and a faulty proof is a faulty proof regardless of who or what produced it. What we were trying to warn you about is simply that AI language models have zero guarantee of providing a truth, especially on stuff like Fourier transforms with a lot of distinct definitions. It could probably tell you that all metric spaces are complete or that all functions are continuous with a straight face and believable, seemingly trustworthy arguments. 1/2

Comment: The community here is a bit agitated in regards to AI language models and chatbots, it's the main reason behind the moderator strike, and there's an increase in its uses or mentions, for example as far as people letting it write nonsensical answers in a row, but hopefully you understand that we don't mean any harm. 2/2

Comment: Ok, thank you @BrunoB for your comments. If someone could answer to my update it would be great, I don't understand how "it depends" can be acceptable for such a duality property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I'll try to show you how the normalisation constant does modify the multiplicative constant when applying the transform twice, among other things.

Let's index all possible standard conventions for the Fourier transforms in the fashion below:
$$\mathcal{F}_{a,b}[f](\xi) := a \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) e^{-ibx\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
where $(a,b) \in (0, \infty) \times (\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})$ (some conventions do use negative $b$ for the direct Fourier transform and not the inverse one yes).
I'll assume that $f$ is for example of Schwartz class for the purpose of this post just to alleviate any issue about integrability, inverse Fourier transforms, etc... but of course you can relax that assumption.

First, let's find the expression of the inverse Fourier transform for each of these conventions. With the previous indexing, we can index inverse Fourier transforms as a Fourier transform with second parameter $-b$, thus we are looking for $c$ such that:
$$\mathcal{F}_{c,-b} \circ \mathcal{F}_{a,b} = \mathrm{id}$$
Instead of redoing the proof of the Fourier inversion theorem for every convention (aka copy-pasting everything while observing the differences) however, we'll write everything with one convention for which we know for certain what the inverse Fourier transform is like. I'll choose $\mathcal{F}_{1,\pm 2\pi}$ simply because we know that $\mathcal{F}_{1,2\pi}^{-1} = \mathcal{F}_{1,-2\pi}$ and vice-versa, which simplifies things quite a bit (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) for example).
We have:
$$\begin{split}
\mathcal{F}_{a,b}[f](\xi) &= a\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{-ibx\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&= a\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) e^{-i2\pi x\frac{b\xi}{2\pi}}\mathrm{d}x\\
&= a\,\mathcal{F}_{1,\,2\pi}[f]\left(\frac{b\xi}{2\pi}\right)
\end{split}$$
Hence, substituting the argument $\xi$ for $\zeta := \frac{b \xi}{2\pi}$ and integrating against $e^{i2\pi \zeta x}$ for some fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have:
$$\frac{1}{a}\int_\mathbb{R} \mathcal{F}_{a,b}[f]\left(\frac{2\pi\zeta}{b}\right)e^{i2\pi \zeta x}\mathrm{d}\zeta = \int_\mathbb{R} \mathcal{F}_{a,b}[f](\zeta)e^{i2\pi \zeta x}\mathrm{d}\zeta = \mathcal{F}_{1,-2\pi}[\mathcal{F}_{1,2\pi}[f]](x) = f(x)$$
Yet the left hand side becomes, going back to $\xi = \frac{2\pi\zeta}{b}$, $\mathrm{d}\xi = \frac{2\pi}{b}\mathrm{d}\zeta$:
$$\frac{1}{a}\int_\mathbb{R} \mathcal{F}_{a,b}[f]\left(\frac{2\pi\zeta}{b}\right)e^{i2\pi \zeta x}\mathrm{d}\zeta = \frac{|b|}{2\pi a}\int_\mathbb{R} \mathcal{F}_{a,b}[f](\xi)e^{ib\xi x}\mathrm{d}\xi$$
where the $|b|$ appears to have the correct orientation of the integral.
Which means that:
$$\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{a,b}[f] = \mathcal{F}_{\frac{|b|}{2\pi a},-b}[f]$$
It can then be checked that this is coherent when reapplying that operation, as we also need to have $\mathcal{F}_{\frac{|b|}{2\pi a},-b}^{-1} = \mathcal{F}_{a,b}$ too:
$$\frac{|-b|}{2\pi\frac{|b|}{2\pi a}} = \frac{|b|}{|b|}\frac{2\pi}{2\pi} a = a$$
Having found the correct normalisation constant for the inverse Fourier transform, we'll now proceed to see which constant comes out when applying the Fourier transform twice in a row:
$$\begin{split}
\mathcal{F}_{a,b}[\mathcal{F}_{a,b}[f]](x) &= a\int_\mathbb{R} \mathcal{F}_{a,b}[f](\xi) e^{-ib\xi x} \,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&= a \cdot \frac{2\pi a}{|b|}\cdot \frac{|b|}{2\pi a}\int_\mathbb{R} \mathcal{F}_{a,b}[f](\xi) e^{-ib\xi x} \,\mathrm{d}\xi\\
&= \frac{2\pi a^2}{|b|}\mathcal{F}_{\frac{|b|}{2\pi a},-b}[\mathcal{F}_{a,b}[f]](-x)\\
&= \frac{2\pi a^2}{|b|}\mathcal{F}_{a,b}^{-1}[\mathcal{F}_{a,b}[f]](-x)\\
&= \frac{2\pi a^2}{|b|}f(-x)
\end{split}$$
which naturally is not in general $C f(-x)$ for some $C$ independent of $a$ and $b$.
This also means that in general we do not have the identity $\mathcal{F}_{a,b}^{\circ 4} = \mathrm{id}$ which is true for $(a,b) = (1, \pm 2\pi)$, but rather $\mathcal{F}_{a,b}^{\circ 4} = \frac{4\pi^2 a^4}{|b|^2}\mathrm{id}$ which is a bit messier.

Hopefully this answers your concerns.